# Differentiation Tricks

Tags: derivatives, differential-forms

Since most derivatives are trivial to take, it's understandable why integrals get most of the mathematical tricksters' attention. However, not all derivatives are trivial to take and I think it's good to have as many tricks up your sleeves as possible. I noticed the other day that $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}=\frac{dx}{dy}$ and that we can use this fact to differentiate functions like the inverse trig functions e.g. $y=\arcsin(x)$, $$\frac{d \sin(y)}{dy}=\cos(y)=\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}$$ My question is, does anybody know of any similar tricks to differentiate those rare functions which are non-trivial?

Answer (score 5):

Logarithmic differentiation.

Given $y=f(x)>0$, we can take $\ln y = \ln f(x)$, and find that $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = f(x) \dfrac{d}{dx} \ln f(x)$.

However, if $|y|=|f(x)|$, then we obtain $\ln |y| = \ln |f(x)|$, and then $\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln |y| = \dfrac{y}{|y|^2}y' =\dfrac{y'}{y}.$

So in fact whether $f(x)$ is positive or negative is of no concern.

This can be used on rational functions, to avoid using the quotient rule, or on functions of the form $y=(f(x))^{g(x)}$.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are positive, no?

Comment: Maybe $\log |y|$?

Comment: @user3491648 Yes you're right, thanks. Logarithms aren't defined for real negative numbers!

Comment: you can edit $\log y$ into $\log |y|$ and then it works as long as $y \not= 0$ which also mean $f(x) \not= 0$

Comment: also $f'(x)/g(x)$ should be $f'(x)/f(x)$

Comment: actually $\frac{d}{dx}\log|x| = \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \not= 0$ so there's no need to say "However if..." By the chain rule $\frac{d}{dx}\log |f(x)| = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ with no condition on $f$ except not being $0$ which is clear from the LHS and RHS

Comment: $\log(-k)=\log(i\pi k)$, no?

Comment: @Archaick $\log(-k) = \log(k) + i\pi$ for $k>0$, which looks like another reason why the sign of $f(x)$ doesn't change the derivative!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d(u^v)}{dx} = \frac{d(e^{v \log u})}{dx} = e^{v \log u}\frac{d(v \log u)}{dx} = u^v (\frac{dv}{dx}\log u + v\frac{du/dx}{u})$$

$$\frac{d(\log_u v)}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{\log v}{ \log u} \right)$$

$$\arccos x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arcsin x \therefore \frac{d}{dx}\arccos x = - \frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x \text{, and so on with $\arctan$ and arccotan.}$$